Named pipe connection over network error (The username or password is incorrect)
When running a solution where one machine runs a server and a second machine runs a client connecting via named pipes I'm having a strange issue.
If both machines run the same Microsoft account, the connection is done successfully. However, if the account is not the same or if any of the accounts are local, the connection fails with a "The username or password is incorrect" exception on the client side.
I already added an access rule where I gave the WorldSid full control so I do not believe it to be a permission issue. I'm however wondering if it is a limitation that I'm not aware of.
Please ignore the code smells and the less than perfect naming/standards, currently I'm only hoping to get this to work, later I'll deal with the other issues.
the following is the code used to create the named pipe on the server side:
// Define security descriptor for the named pipe
        PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();

        var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
        var account = (NTAccount)sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

        // Add an access rule allowing Everyone to connect to the pipe
        pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(account.ToString(), PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

        PipeServer = NamedPipeServerStreamConstructors.New(CurrentPipeState.PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, -1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 0, 0, pipeSecurity);

Note, that due to using a .Net framework version which lacked the native constructor, I had to use a plugin that copied the constructor that took pipeSecurity as an argument from another version. This should not change anything since the code is the same, but it explains the different naming for the initialization.
The client pipe is created with the following code:
CoreEventPipeWrapper = new CoreControlEventNamedPipeWrapper("CorePipe", CoreControlEventNamedPipeWrapper.Type.CLIENT);
            CoreEventPipeWrapper.CurrentPipeState.OriginMachineName = CoreClientName;
            CoreEventPipeWrapper.OnClientConnected += onCoreClientConnection;
            Task.Run(() => CoreEventPipeWrapper.Connect<CoreControlEvent>(CoreServerIp));

The wrapper  being used just "hides" the marshalling of data and uses
        PipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(serverName, CurrentPipeState.PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);


for the connection

Windows authentication doesn't work with names. Whether it's a local folder, file share or named pipe, access is based on the user account, not the name. In Active Directory domains, that means the application must run under an account that has permission to connect to the pipe or access the shared folder. That's the most common case as all companies use AD. In non-domain ("workgroupd") environments the remote machine must have an account that has exactly the same name and password as the local one
